# Why do the commands `\section*{}` and `\header{}{}` generate an error in my MWE?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have been (unsuccessfully) trying to change the fonts of my CV, and it turns out that now the commands `\section*` and `\header` fail (whereas they used to work just fine before the last changes I made). I have spent many hours trying to figure out why these commands now fail, but I haven’t been successful.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% FONTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[]{xcolor}

\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Color=textcolor,Path=fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Reg,ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig}

\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text,Path=fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont
[BoldFont=fonts/lato/Lato-Bol.ttf,
ItalicFont=fonts/lato/Lato-Reg.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=fonts/lato/Lato-BolIta.ttf]
{fonts/lato/Lato-Reg.ttf}

\newfontfamily\thinfont
[BoldFont=fonts/lato/Lato-Bol.ttf,
ItalicFont=fonts/lato/Lato-Reg.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=fonts/lato/Lato-BolIta.ttf]
{fonts/lato/Lato-Reg.ttf}

\newfontfamily\headingfont
[BoldFont=fonts/lato/Lato-Bol.ttf,
ItalicFont=fonts/lato/Lato-Reg.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=fonts/lato/Lato-BolIta.ttf]
{fonts/lato/Lato-Bol.ttf}

\newfontfamily\fontawesome[]{FontAwesome.otf}

\setfontfamily\fontawesome[]{fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf}

% HEADER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
  \thinfont%
  \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=5cm,yshift=00.00pt] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{black}%
      {\bodyfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{30pt}
}

% STRUCTURE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{parskip}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{black}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\newcommand{\sectionx}[1]{
  {%
    \Large\headingfont\color{black}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  {%
  \large\headingfont\color{black} #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}

% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
\header{Name}{Surname}

\section*{Education}
 
Hello!
   
\end{document}
```

The above MWE generates no output but a ton of errors. If one comments the lines `\header{Name}{Surname}` and `\section*{Education}`, the MWE above displays no errors (assuming, of course, that the corresponding fonts are in the specified folder).

Similarly, if one comments the lines `\LARGE\headingfont\color{black}%`, `\@sectioncolor #1%`, `\Large\headingfont\color{black}%`, `\@sectioncolor #1%` and `\header{Name}{Surname}`, the MWE above displays no errors (assuming, again, that the corresponding fonts are in the specified folder).

Also, the fonts I am using can be found here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cv/bjryvfsjdyxz (and probably somewhere else too, but I don’t know where).

*Can anybody help me find and correct whatever it is that is generating these errors?*

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time.

Comment: If I change the fonts to ones I have I get an error `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color \`fillheader'.` as that color is not defined

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have erased the bit `fill=fillheader`, but it makes no difference. I still get no output and many errors unless I erase the specified lines above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMPORTANT

Do not use the Overleaf fonts. Get the fonts with the right user license from

[Download Lato TTF Fonts](https://www.latofonts.com/download/lato2ofl-zip/)

These 18 font files are in the `\font\lato` directory of the working directory (windows OS).

[image: a]

The redefinition of `\section` does not include the section number.  `\section*` is neither defined nor necessary.

The color `fillheader` orange-like was defined and a space was added between Name and Surname.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

% FONTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{fillheader}{cmyk}{0,0.5,1,0}     %  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

%\setmainfont[Color=textcolor,Path=fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Reg,ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig}
%
%\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text,Path=fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[%%  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
Path=fonts/lato/,
Extension = .ttf,%
UprightFont=*-Regular,%
BoldFont = *-Semibold,%
ItalicFont=*-Italic,%
BoldItalicFont = *-SemiboldItalic,
]{Lato}

\newfontfamily\headingfont[%%  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
Path=fonts/lato/,
Extension = .ttf,%
UprightFont=*-Black,%
BoldFont = *-Bold,%
ItalicFont=*-BlackItalic,%
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{Lato}

\newfontfamily\thinfont[%%  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
Path=fonts/lato/,
Extension = .ttf,%
UprightFont=*-Light,%
BoldFont = *-Medium,%
ItalicFont=*-LightItalic,%
]{Lato}

% HEADER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
    \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
    \thinfont%
    \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=5cm,yshift=00.00pt] (box) at (current page.north){};
        \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
            \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{black}%
            {\bodyfont #1\enspace}{\bodyfont  #2} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{30pt}
}

% STRUCTURE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{parskip}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{ % stared version not defined
    \par\vspace{\parskip}
    {%
        \LARGE\headingfont\color{black}%
%       \@sectioncolor %  changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
         #1%
    }
    \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\newcommand{\sectionx}[1]{
    {%
        \Large\headingfont\color{black}%
        \@sectioncolor #1%  @sectioncolor ?????????????
    }
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
    {%
        \large\headingfont\color{black} #1%
    }
    \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}

% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
\header{Name}{Surname}

\section{Education} %  changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\verb|bodyfont| => {\bodyfont   Hello!  \textbf{Hello!}  \emph{Hello!}}

\verb|headingfont| => {\headingfont Hello!  \textbf{Hello!}  \emph{Hello!}}

\verb|thinfont| => {\thinfont       Hello!  \textbf{Hello!}  \emph{Hello!}}
    
\end{document}
```